# Is dummy trap variable really a problem?

Tags: categorical-data, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

My goal is to encode a 'Education_Level' which have values 'Uneducated', 'High School', 'College', 'Graduate', 'Post-Graduate', 'Doctorate'.

The problem is that if I drop the first column (in this case 'Uneducated'), then I can't differentiate between 'Uneducated' and unknown category.

i.e. 'Uneducated' and unknown category will have equal row '[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]'.

I was thinking to NOT drop the first column. However, I am worried because of the effect (never had the chance to test it with a dataset from Kaggle)

What I've tried:

1. Tried to prove that the encoder can't differentiate between 'Uneducated' and unknown category.

```
education = ['Graduate','High School','Unknown','Uneducated','College','Post-Graduate',
             'Doctorate']
X = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Education_Level': education + education + education,
    'Age': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
})

X_nom = X['Education_Level'].values.reshape(-1,1)

ohc_enc = OneHotEncoder(categories=[
    ['Uneducated', 'High School', 'College', 'Graduate', 'Post-Graduate', 'Doctorate']
], handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist', drop='first').fit(X=X_nom)

X_encoded_2 = ohc_enc.transform(X=X_nom).toarray()

# print(X_encoded_2)

print(ohc_enc.inverse_transform(X_encoded_2))
```

Output

```
[['Graduate']
 ['High School']
 ['Uneducated'] -> This should be [None], instead if become ['Uneducated']
 ['Uneducated']
 ['College']
 ['Post-Graduate']
 ['Doctorate']
 ['Graduate']
 ['High School']
 ['Uneducated']
 ['Uneducated']
 ['College']
 ['Post-Graduate']
 ['Doctorate']
 ['Graduate']
 ['High School']
 ['Uneducated']
 ['Uneducated']
 ['College']
 ['Post-Graduate']
 ['Doctorate']]
```

Comment: Why are you not putting the unknown category in a new category? Then you will be able to differentiate it.

Comment: @user2974951 Ah, sorry. I was doing GridSearchCV yesterday and the encoder throws warning of unknown category, I though this will be a problem if the train set do not have at least 1 row with value 'Unknown'. I was about to give you the problem, it turns out setting the `OneHotEncoder(categories=[['Unknown', etc]])` solves the problem.